# Basic information about Couch Database

Tags: couchdb

In couch db how many maximum number of creation of user are possible and is there any kind of limit and i also want to know ,is there any limit for creation of databases?????

Answer (score 1):

Users are just entries in an user database. I have yet to encounter any problems with having too many users, except of course for running out of disk space.

There are also no built-in restrictions on the number of databases, however databases are mapped to files on the disk and are therefore subject to file system limitations such as having too many files in a single directory, or opening too many file descriptors at once. These limits can be raised, but don't expect to have more than a few thousand active databases at once.

[This might be of interest to you, as well.](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance#Resource_Limits)